# Ruby pdf-reader adds blank rows where none exist when parsing PDF

Tags: ruby, parsing, pdf-reader

I'm building a tool to parse PDFs of CVs downloaded from Linkedin. But when I parse the document, `pdf-reader` finds blank rows where none exist to the eye.

I'm wondering if this is a problem with the PDF or the PDF Reader?

**Script**

```
require 'pdf-reader'

reader = PDF::Reader.new("CV.pdf")

reader.pages.each_with_index do |page, page_num|
    bits = page.text.split("\n")

    bits.each_with_index do |bit, index|
        puts bit
    end
end
```

**Snapshot of CV**

[image]

**Parsed Output**

```
Senior Analyst
September 2013 - August 2015 (1 year 11 months)
  - Managed a team of analysts to drive operational improvement across all departments of a subsidiary

   company, including a 33% increase in conversions on their e-commerce platform and a 8% decrease in
   logistics costs within my first year
```

You'll notice in the outputted text that there is a blank line added to the middle of the sentence.

It seems odd, because if you look at the screenshot of the PDF, it doesn't appear to have any blank row where the pdf reader finds one.

Does anyone have experience with what might cause this?

Answer (score 0):

After trying other libraries, it appears the problem was `pdf-reader`, not the PDF.

So I decided on another gem called `Yomu` (see: https://github.com/Erol/yomu), which avoided the issue.

Its a little bit slower, but acceptable given the increased predictability of output.